# Need help animating an Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in my Android application. The individual views in the list are a little bit smaller than the size of the screen.

I want the list to always show one item centered in the screen, with just a small sliver of the previous and next items showing above and below it.

When the user scrolls, I need to reposition the child view at position 0 or 1 (depending on which way they are scrolling). Currently I am doing this by calling "setSelectionFromTop" in my onScrollStateChanged method. This works, but the transition is immediate, not smooth. It is jarring and confusing in a lot of cases.

What's the best approach to fixing this? I want to animate the process of scrolling the list into the position I want, but I can't find any methods in ListView or its superclasses that let me directly control the scroll position of the entire list.

I think I could animate it using multiple calls to setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y) with progressive values of y, but I don't know how to determine the initial value of y. Is there some way to get that by interrogating the view object at the designated position?

Another challenge I have in front of me is that I want to animate the removal of an item from the list - by having it either disappear or slide away to the left, and then having the surrounding views move up and down to fill the space. Is there a straightforward and reliable way to do this with a ListView? Should I just give up on the ListView and write the whole thing as a custom view from scratch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely should be possible. Does `smoothScrollToPosition()` work?

Otherwise, you can try simulating the touches using [TouchUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html).